# Node.js async.each does not wait to iterate

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm going mad trying to figure out what I am doing wrong with this synchronous iterator in node.js, using async:

```
async.each(ids, function(id,next) {
                console.log(id);
                tokens.addID(id,function (id_uuid) {
                    console.log('Added ID '+id_uuid);
                    next();

                });
});
```

The problem is that the inner call back is not being waited on before the next iteration occurs. But that makes no sense. I've wasted hours, very grateful for any help.

Comment: I think `each` will execute that function for each item in parallel, so the `next` serves just to notify this execution has finished and not to start the next one. See https://github.com/caolan/async#each and `eachSeries`

Comment: Thank you. I'm hoping this is a more common misunderstanding than just my own stupidity.

Comment: This should not have been downvoted. This is actually a helpful question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is a very simple misunderstanding of the meanings of the async function names. `async.each` executes them all in parallel. You want `async.series` to execute them one at a time, in order.

Comment: In case of misunderstanding, really thank you. I feel incredibly stupid and wasted a lot of time.