# Why async.each does not run the iterations in parallel?

Tags: node.js, asynchronous

To understand and look the behaviour of `async.each` I wrote some lines, but in my case it seems that the iterations are not run in parallel, is it because I'm using the `console.log` to check where the code is ?

**JS Server**

```
let server = http.createServer(function (req, res) {
    res.writeHead(200);
    let datas = [1, 2, 3, 4];
    async.each(datas, function (data, callback) {
        console.log(data);
        for (let i = 0; i < 1000 * 1000 * 1000 * 2; i++) { // the loop takes about 1-2sec
            let b = i * i;
            b += 2
        }
        console.log(data);
        callback()
    }, function (err) {
        console.log("callback ", err ? err : "");
        res.end('Hey');
    })
});
server.listen(8080);
```

it prints :

```
1
1
2
2
3
3
4
4
callback
```

---

The sources that explain why I expect the parallelism

- [async module doc](https://caolan.github.io/async/v3/docs.html#each)
- [Node.js async.each does not wait to iterate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25224252/node-js-async-each-does-not-wait-to-iterate#answers)

---

**WORKING EXAMPLE**

A web request is non-blocking and does not take all the cpu so it works

```
const async = require('async');
const http = require('http');
const request = require('request');
const url = 'https://caolan.github.io/async/v3/docs.html'; // input your url here

let server = http.createServer(function (req, res) {
    res.writeHead(200);
    let datas = [1, 2, 3, 4];
    async.each(datas, function (data, callback) {
        console.log(data);
        request({url: url}, function (err, res, body) {
            const rr = body.indexOf("Processing") + body.indexOf("until");
            console.log(data, " ", new Date().getTime());
        });
        callback()
    }, function (err) {
        console.log("callback ", err ? err : "");
        res.end('Salut tout le monde !');
    })
});
server.listen(8080);
```

Gives

```
1
2
3
4
callback
1 ' ' 1565298694448
3 ' ' 1565298694555
4 ' ' 1565298694569
2 ' ' 1565298694576
```

Comment: JavaScript is single-threaded. `async.each()` does not allow parallelism, it allows asynchronous concurrency, but your function is not asynchronous, so nothing will happen concurrently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your loops are CPU bound, you're going to pin the process and there's no chance to yield for the next task. This isn't non-blocking code, this blocks, so it'll be sequential.

Remember, JavaScript code never really runs in parallel, it's locked to one thread under normal conditions, it just runs *concurrently*. To get that to happen your code must yield, it can't monopolize the thread.

Comment: For this kind of question, I think elaborating what is meant by "CPU bound" and "non-blocking" (and specifically why the code in the example is considered as such) would be helpful.

Comment: So what kind of action can be run in parallel ? What kind of cases ?

Comment: For compute-heavy tasks where you will necessarily monopolize a thread then you'll have to use [WebWorkers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API/Using_web_workers) to provide additional resources and free up your main JavaScript thread. You can run anything in parallel *if* you have different threads, or if the activities aren't going to use 100% of the CPU and they can share.

Comment: @tadman web workers are a browser-specific API. In Node.js, [`child_process.fork()`](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_fork_modulepath_args_options) or the more recent [worker threads](https://nodejs.org/api/worker_threads.html) would be an appropriate solution.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts Yeah, Worker Threads are an attempt to bring WebWorkers to Node.js. There's several packages on NPM that provide the WebWorkers API though.